# What attributes are not stored in __dict__ and why are they not?

Tags: python

In Python, a lot of the "special" attributes of objects are stored in the `__dict__` dictionary, like `__doc__`, `__module__` (from what I could see in my experiments).

However some are not, like `__class__`. My question is exactly which attributes are not stored in `__dict__` (is that even documented somewhere?), and why are they not?

Comment: maybe this could be useful, a chapter on attribute resolution: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/ch01.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what `__dict__` you are talking about. Python has a method resolution order that (ignoring the fun of multiple inheritance) works by checking the instance, then the class, then the parent class, then it's parent class, etc...

So `__class__`, for instance, is in `object.__dict__` - which is why it's defined for all classes as they inherit from `object`.

Comment: So you are saying all attributes (without exception) are in a dictionary somewhere? And does object.__dict__ return the proper value depending on which type it is called on (because as far as I can see, it's not overriden when you create a class)?

Comment: Not quite - there is also [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots), and `object.__dict__` is just a dictionary - the functions contained it it will be designed to produce the correct (default) results on all objects.